# How do I add a comment?

Tags: support, comments, reputation

I have seen people add a comment but I can't see that link anywhere in my questions.

Is there a need for a certain amount of reputation to comment?

Answer (score 5):

You need **at least 50 reputation** in order to add comments to any post. However, until then, you should always be able to post comments on **your own questions and answers, and any answers to your own questions**.

The otion should be "add comment" and should be located in the bottom left of any eligible post, as shown below using your question here on Meta.

[image: Quick Screenshot]

Comment: wow thanks that was really helpful.Gee didn't know that thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1):

See

https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

under "Leave Comments" (and be sure to read the footnote, too!)